# Query with calculated measurement using olap4j QueryDimension

Tags: pentaho, olap4j

I am using olap4j to query my rolap cube (underlying implementation is pentaho).

I could not found any way to add on-the-fly calculated measurement to the query while using the org.olap4j.query package.(there is a way when using the low level api in org.olap4j.mdx package)

Is there any support of olap4j for calculated measurements that I am missing?

Yosi

Answer (score 0):

So far, calculated members are not a concept supported by the query model. There are other query models available out there; some might support them.

If you are interested in working in that area, or just getting more information, I suggest you join the olap4j [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/olap4j-devel).